# lookup task (ssis)

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, lookup, task

I just need the confirmation.

Tell me if I am wrong.

A package consists of an oledb source editor which consists of a query followed by three lookups. If I do a preview on each task, every task (oledb source, and the first two lookups) except for the last lookup has values in the respective tables. So, my claim is: if there is no data in the last lookup table the final resultset that comes out of the last look up should be empty.

Help appreciated.

Comment: This question was very unclear, so I'm voting to close it as a duplicate of the question he asked because he didn't get an answer to this one: that one, at least, is clearer.

Comment: So you're asking - "if a lookup fails are those rows excluded"?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you handle errors it will either throw an error (red component) or be redirected/ignored. So you are somewhat correct with your assumption.